# React - Mui - Autocomplete - asks for keys

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, key

console: Warning: Encountered two children with the same key

how can i add keys?

i tried

```
 <Stack spacing={2} sx={{ width: 300 }}>
        <Autocomplete
          id="free-solo-demo"
          freeSolo
          options={cityObj.map((option) => option.name)}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              error={weatherData?.error ? true : false}
              fullWidth
              label="name your city here..."
              value={search}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setSearch(e.target.value);
              }}
              ref={inputField}
              onKeyDown={(e) => e.key === "Enter" && handleSubmit(e)}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Stack>
```

Comment: You need to add key={Math.random()} to the TextField

Comment: You should get the key from your component somewhere, some unique object

Comment: i got a uniqe id for each item in my list but i cant add key property to the TextField so where should i add key property for each item

Comment: These `key` errors appear when you map/loop over some array, I don't see how you can have such an error here

Comment: That error appears during a map/loop. Please provide the full code where a map/loop is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Autocomplete` automatically maps your options and put the option value as key for each option.
So evidently you have some duplicate `name` values in in your `cityObj` array.
I don't know if there is a way to change the keys in order to suppress the warning, but even if there is, I recommend to not fiddling with it and fixing the problem in a **correct** manner by **removing the duplicate value from your options array**. Because why would we have two or more identical options in a autocomplete anyway?